# Compresión de archivos en vb.net al guardar en base de datos PostgresQL 9.3

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, postgresql-9.3, dropzone.js

Tengo el siguiente planteamiento al que no le he encontrado soluciones.

Tengo una base de datos PostgresQL en un sevidor y una web en otro. Esta web (intranet) tiene la capacidad de guardar archivos word, pdf, zip y pdf. A final de cuentas, la base de datos está muy pesada en la tabla de archivos (cerca de 13GB en archivos SQL y 7 GB en archivos.backup) y necesito comprimir o guardar los archivos de tal manera que estos queden comprimidos. Además de poder cargar archivos tambien se pueden descargar a través de la página, por lo que necesito además algún método de inversión para la compresión.

Estos son en resumen mis codigos:

Un Handler:

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        Try
            cn.Conectar()
            cnArchivos = context
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
            Dim dirFullPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/")
            Dim files As String()
            Dim numfiles As Integer
            files = Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath)
            numfiles = files.Length + 1
            idAccion = context.Request.Params("nAccion")
            idUsuario = context.Request.Params("idUsuario")
            Using con As New conexion
                con.Conectar()
                Dim str_image As String = ""
                For Each s As String In context.Request.Files

                    Dim txtSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM observaciones.adjuntos WHERE id=0"
                    Dim da As New Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter(txtSQL, con.conexion)
                    Dim tabla As DataTable = cn.DataTable(txtSQL)
                    Dim cb As Npgsql.NpgsqlCommandBuilder = New Npgsql.NpgsqlCommandBuilder(da)
                    Dim fs As FileStream
                    Dim rw As DataRow
                    Dim ruta As String
                    Dim comp As Boolean = False
                    Dim largo As Long = 0


                    Dim file As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files(s)
                    fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName)
                    fileNameExt = file.FileName
                    Dim fileExtension As String = file.ContentType
                    ruta = dirFullPath + fileNameExt

                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) Then
                        If ValidaNombreArchivoAdjunto(fileNameExt, context.Request.Params(1), context.Request.Params(0)) Then
                            fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName)
                            str_image = fileName
                            file.SaveAs(ruta)

                            fs = New FileStream(ruta, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                            Dim dataArchivo(fs.Length - 1) As Byte
                            fs.Read(dataArchivo, 0, fs.Length)
                            fs.Close()
                            Dim md5 As String = GeneraCodigoMD5(dataArchivo)
                            largo = dataArchivo.Length
                            If ruta.Substring(ruta.LastIndexOf(".")).ToLower = ".mdb" Then
                                dataArchivo = Comprime(dataArchivo)
                                comp = True
                            End If

                            Dim adjunto_ = New ClaseAdjunto()
                            adjunto_.id_ = 1
                            adjunto_.nombre_ = fileName
                            adjunto_.rutaCompleta_ = dirFullPath
                            adjunto_.comprimido = False
                            adjunto_.md5_ = ""
                            adjunto_.nbytes_ = context.Request.Files(s).ContentLength

                            rw = tabla.NewRow()
                            rw("id") = 1   'se asigna el valor automatico en la tabla
                            rw("id_accion") = idAccion
                            rw("ruta") = ruta
                            rw("archivo") = dataArchivo
                            'Mejora HRIFO 04-07-2016, Normalizacion de nomenclatura
                            rw("nombre") = fileName
                            'rw("nombre") = ruta.Substring(ruta.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
                            'Fin mejora
                            rw("md5") = md5
                            rw("nbytes") = largo
                            rw("comprimido") = If(comp, "s", "n")


                            tabla.Rows.Add(rw)
                            da.Update(tabla)
                            correoArchivo(fileName, largo, idAccion)
                            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(ruta)
                            context.Response.Write(str_image)

                            'Dim pathToSave_100 As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") & str_image
                            'file.SaveAs(pathToSave_100)


                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error de archivo")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

DropzoneJS:

```
<!-- Cargar archivos a derivado Modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalCargaArchivo" tabindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="H1">
                        Cargar archivos a observación</h5>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="dropzone"  action="/" >
                        <div id="myDrop" class="dropzone">
                            <div class="dz-message">Arrastra archivos acá</div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mainZone"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="Button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="reload()">Listo</button>
                    <div id="main2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
//Configurar Dropzone
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div#myDrop").dropzone({
            url: '../hnFileUpDropzone.ashx',
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            maxFilesize: 10,
            maxFiles: 3,
            dictRemoveFile : "Borrar",
            dictDefaultMessage: "Arrastra archivos o haz click acá",
            dictCancelUpload: "Cancelar carga",
            dictUploadCanceled: "Carga cancelada",
            dictCancelUploadConfirmation: "¿Esta seguro que desea cancelar la carga del archivo?",
            dictInvalidFileType: "No puedes subir archivos de este tipo" , 
            acceptedFiles: ".doc,.docx,.mdb,.gdb,.zip,.rar",
            init: function(){
                this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
                    formData.append("nObserva", nObserva);
                    formData.append("nHoja", nArea);
                    formData.append("nAccion", nAccion);
                    formData.append("idUsuario", idUsuario);
                    $('#mainZone').html("<img id='barZone' src='img/loader.gif'  height='50' width='50'  />").show();
                })
            },
            success: function(file, response){
                var imgName=response;
                file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
                $('#barZone').hide();
            },
            error: function(file, message){
                $(file.previewElement).addClass("dz-error").find('.dz-error-message').text("Error encontrado: " + message);
            }
        });
    });
```

Y el esquema de mi tabla de Base de Datos:

```
CREATE TABLE adjuntos{
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('misecuencia'),
id_accuib integer,
archivo bytea,
ruta text,
nombre character(120),
md5 character(32),
nbytes integer,
comprimido "char",
CONSTRAINT pk_id_adjunto PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_id_accion FOREING KEY(id_accion)

}
```

Muchas gracias por su orientación.
Saludos

Comment: Entiendo que estás almacenando los archivos en la misma base de datos? Yo te recomendaría directamente sacarles de ahi, almacenarles en una ruta fisica del servidor, y en la base de datos solo guardar la ruta.

Comment: Excelente idea que de hecho implementaré, pero al almacenarlos de forma física aún así tendría el problema de espacio. Gracias @Pikoh

Comment: Es posible, aunque al final los archivos ocupan espacio logicamente, y si son muchos ocuparan mucho espacio. Pero de esa manera es muy sencillo comprimir los archivos al subirles, y descomprimirles al bajarles. Esto ultimo tambien podrías hacerlo en la misma base de datos. écha un vistazo a [Compression](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.compression?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siento contarte que no vas a conseguir liberar mucho espacio. Los archivos de Office (Word -docx-, Excel -xlsx-, etc.) son en realidad un `.zip` con la extensión cambiada, por lo que volviéndolos a comprimir, no vas a ganar mucho. Respecto de los PDF, va a depender de su contenido, pero tampoco tengas muchas expectativas.

Por otro lado, [tienes disponible una clase](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netframework-4.8) en `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` llamada `ZipFile`, que junto a `GZipStream` te dan las herramientas que necesitas. Solo debes tener cuidado en caso de archivos muy voluminosos para no colocarlos por completo en memoria. En [este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#Anchor_6) tienes algún ejemplo.

El código es sencillo, pero dependerá de la secuencia que realices. Si manejas archivos desde el inicio o bien un stream. Con el método Stream.CopyTo conseguimos leer los bytes del stream actual y escribir en otro stream utilizando el tamaño del buffer configurado (por defecto  (81920 bytes).

```
void ComprimeArchivo (string PathEntrada, string PathSalida)
{
    using (FileStream ArchivoEntrada = File.OpenRead(PathEntrada))
    using (FileStream ArchivoSalida = File.Create(PathSalida))
    using (GZipStream output = new GZipStream(ArchivoSalida, CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        ArchivoSalida.CopyTo(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, implementé esta clase para los archivos mas pesados y todo bien!